# Rendering a Transparent Object (with Outline added by Nodes) on a Transparent Background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, transparency

Hey there Blender Community,

I am attempting to render just the outline of a fully transparent object on a transparent background (in Cycles). Using a material index pass and an inverse Sobel filter, I am able to produce the outline effect successfully on a white background. See below:

[image: Functioning Object Outline on White Background]

However, when I make the film (the background) transparent, the outline disappears. Is there a way to keep the black outline of the fully transparent object on an a transparent background?

The same node setup, but with film set to transparent:

[image: Nonfunctional Object Outline on Transparent Background]

My thanks in advance for any assistance or pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, and probably there is a better one, but if I understand correctly maybe this will help:

[image]

<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

Using a [*Color Key*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/matte/color_key.html#color-key-node) node to replace the white with transparent pixels, and adding the key to the image  seems to work well in this case.

Comment: This worked beautifully for me. (And I'd say that adding only one node is a pretty elegant solution.) Thanks very much! @Timaroberts

Comment: @ColinConwell, you're welcome. Glad to help.

Comment: One question: Would it possible to somehow animate this? Such that the color drained out over some number of frames?